# In C++ should there be a space between the function name and the brackets?

Tags: c++

In the code below:

```
int main () {cout << "hello world";}
```

should there be a space between the function name and the parenthesis?  If either is excepted by the compiler what is te convention?

Comment: Afaik there is no single convention. I have definitely seen both.

Comment: @Dr.Person: Um `{}` are "braces". "Brackets" is an accepted synonym for parenthesis.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit You are right but isn't "parenthesis" more precise and unambiguous, like the phrasing of the current question? PS I have no idea have to use the @ feature with your username that has spaces.

Comment: @Dr.PersonPersonII: You could use the auto-complete feature that pops up when you type `@`, either to perform the notification, or at least to show you the format you're supposed to type. As it happens, "@Lightness" is sufficient. And no parenthesis isn't really "more unambiguous" because it _technically_ refers to the entire `()` grouping but is often used to refer to the individual glyphs.

Comment: @Lightness When it says "brackets", it could mean the parentheses or the curly brackets. We are in agreement about that now. But the questioner is not asking about the curly brackets at all. Why not eliminate the few seconds of confusion by changing the question to avoid that?

Comment: @Dr.PersonPersonII: No, "curly brackets" is a synonym for "braces", which look like this: `{}`. Please avoid _creating_ confusion by making edits to questions on topics you don't fully understand. Everybody else is not confused.

Comment: @Lightness. YOU are confused and you didn't answer my last question. You are the one that said "brackets" can also stand for "braces". And my last question makes perfect sense if you stop for a second and think about it.

Comment: @Dr.PersonPersonII: _"You are the one that said 'brackets' can also stand for 'braces'."_ I said no such thing.

Comment: @Lightness. You did not. By pointing out "brackets" stand stand for "parentheses" I learned that they can also stand for "braces", which I assumed you also agreed with, which I why I stated so above. That's the crux of the disagreement then, "brackets" can stand for both "parenthesis" AND "curly braces" (aka "curly *brackets*). Hence the whole reason why this title is needlessly confusing.

Comment: @Dr.PersonPersonII _"I learned that they can also stand for 'braces', which I assumed you also agreed with"_ Well, don't assume. I didn't say that, and it's wrong. No-one else is confused here but you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The compiler does not care, but a common convention is to use no space.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, spaces are only required to clarify where symbols are seperate, where symbols are sequences of letters, numbers, and underscores.  Vaguely related, all preprocessor commands must end in a newline.

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){char a=4+3;std::cout<<a<<std::endl;return 0;}
   ^           ^                                    ^
```

In this example, I have a space between `int` and `main`, because otherwise the compiler would think it was a function with no return type named `intmain`.  Same with `char a` being two symbols (not a variable named `chara`, and `return 0` is also two symbols, and not some expression `return0`.

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace in your example is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the coding standard. If there is none, then on the person writing the code.

Comment: coding standard, e.g. the GNU C style encourages function calls to look `like_this (and, that);` among other (sometimes idiosyncratic) preferences. and not bashing them, but to be fair, if you try writing a bit of GLib/GTK+ code, visual aids like this start to seem necessary ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When overloading operators, it tends to increase readability a bit, but in most cases, it's superfluous.